# Is there any hashmap that put method with thread-safe but get method with thread-unsafe

Tags: java, hashmap

I’m setting up a new server, and want to put huge amount of elements to a hashmap at the server's initial time for save initial time, so I want the hashmap's put method is thread-safe. But after the initial time, the hashmap will no change and readonly, so I want the hashmap's get method is thread-unsafe is enough to get better performance.

If I use ConcurrentHashMap to set up the server, it will not good enough when get elements with multi-thread.

So is there any hashmap that put method with thread-safe and get method with thread-unsafe.

Comment: How can you _not_ have a thread-safe `get`? `get` does not mutate the map so it is guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Since you create the read-only map at the server's initial time and no one is going to change it, I think `HashMap` is enough.

Comment: Why does `put()` need to be thread-safe?

Comment: **If I use ConcurrentHashMap to set up the server, it will not good enough when get elements with multi-thread.** have you proved that with sufficient benchmarks?

Comment: @Sweeper just like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380668/java-hashmap-readonly-thread-safety

Comment: @LHCHIN  yes,that just alright, but at the server's initial time, I want to speed up the process  "put huge amount of elements to the HashMap with multi-thread,it must be thread-safe at server's initial time". if I use HashMap, it is too slow for initializing with single thread. I just want a high performance hashmap at initial time just like ConcurrentHashMap, and use it as a read-only simple map as HashMap.

Comment: @shmosel speed up the process of server's initial time with multi-thread.(put huge amount of elements to the HashMap)

Comment: What are the threads doing? Parallelizing `put()` itself won't speed things up.

Comment: @Ivan another objective is to reduce the memory overhead. ConcurrentHashMap has a complicated internal structure. If I select a simple read-only hashmap(there are many 3rd implement of read-only hashmap with high performance, meanwhile with a smaller memory ). It will save much memory for the server.

Comment: @shmosel If I use a read-only map such as HashMap. And parallelizing  won't work. How can I speed up the initial time? Put huge amount of elements to the HashMap at the server's initial time(After the initial time, the Map is read-only).

Comment: the server has 20 cores, so I can use such as 40 threads to help speeding up the inital time.

Comment: I agreed with @Ivan about his comment. As far as I know, `ConcurrentHashMap` has bad performance only operating it with single thread. Therefore, have you compared the performance between `ConcurrentHashMap` and `HashMap` for `get` element?

Comment: @LHCHIN I‘didn't compared the performance between ConcurrentHashMap and HashMap. At first, I choice ConcurrentHashMap,it work well, but I found it cost too much memory, so I droped this solution, and try to find a read-only simple map in order to reduce memory cost. But if select read-only simple map involve another problem "bad experience at servver initialhizing"

Comment: @LHCHIN So is there any other solution to reduce the memory overhead compared with the ConcurrentHashMap's solution.I have more than 35 million elements, so I want to select a simple hashmap to reduce memory. My goal is "Reducing memory usage of very large HashMap"

Comment: I have already done many ways to reduce memory, such as use bit-field with elements, but it is not enough, I want to reduce more memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ConcurrentHashMap` is not good for you due to additional footprint then you can do the following. For each thread you are using to populate map upon startup create its own `HashMap` and populate it. After that you merge all those maps into one `HashMap` (doing it in single thread or using 1 thread to merge maps from threads 1 and 2, using thread 3 to merge maps from threads 3 and 4 and so on and then repeating this until you end up with single large map). And after that you can use that `HashMap` in read-only mode.